# Update value in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have to add new value (or edit actual) `company`. I tried this code in console:

```
db.users.update({email: /debute/},{company: "test"})
```

But now, in database I have only `_id` and `company`. Why other values removed? Or how can I prevent of removing other values in future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the `update` function replaces the entire document with the document you pass. But you can also use it to only replace individual fields and leave the others alone by using the [$set operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/).

```
db.users.update({email: /debute/},{ $set: { company: "test"} } );
```

You might also want to specify a third argument `{ multi: true }` to the update. Otherwise it will only update the first document it finds which matches the condition.

Comment: Actualy, I need just the first match, but anyway good point, I will use it one of these days, so thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use an [update operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/) on order to update an existing document, your code replaces the document with the new document. Here is how to do an update:

```
db.users.update({email: /debute/},{$set: {company: "test"}})
```